# How to keep the "customized error" when using msdeploy to import and synchronize IIS?

Tags: iis

My issue is, when I entered into the directory and press the command in the cmd:

**msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package="C:\Users\ARAXI\Desktop\Backup_20141208053157\IIS\IIS.zip",encryptPassword=a5ha5vf4.0wx -dest:webserver,computername=IPPSAT1RED2K8 -disableRule:IISConfigFrom64To32**

It gave me this:

An error occured when the request was processed on the remote server, Attempted the read or write protected memory, this is often indication that other memory is corrupt.The Error count: 1

---

Again I found an interesting thing——If I commented the below things out, it can work successfully:

```
<section name="httpErrors" allowDefinition="Everywhere" overrideModeDefault="Allow" allowLocation="true" type="" MSDeploy.MSDeployKeyAttributeName="name" />
```

2) all of the sections mapping to 1), the sample is:

```
<section name="system.webServer/httpErrors" overrideMode="Inherit" MSDeploy.MSDeployKeyAttributeName="name">
…………
</section>
```

Is that bug of msdeploy2 from http://forums.iis.net/t/1175950.aspx ?

So I DON'T want to do so, what I want is to keep all of these things and let msdeploy can automatically import things. So how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is Microsoft's Bug, and the solution is to use msdeploy (version3.5).